# HTTPS via CURL and SSL

Tags: ssl, curl

CURL have good timing information. I use  **-w** @curl-format.txt and write the timing results into a CSV file. This works fine.
I make a HTTPS request, is there a way to see the timings for the SSL Steps e.g. for OCSP or for every certificate check step?

The curl parameter **-k** accept any SSL certificate, but mean -k : A) that curl doesn't check the certificate or B) that curl checks the certificate but ignore the result?

Comment: I doubt that curl is currently doing OCSP at all. And the other steps for certificate verification will not reach out to some host, so they don't need their own timing.

Comment: Steffen is right, curl doesn't do OCSP.

Comment: Thanks, do you have some ideas to the second part of the question, the implementation of the CURL -k parameter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that curl just disables verification instead of throwing the result of the verification away. Probably everybody does it this way.

Comment: I guess it too, but I don't know it really. I can't verify this.